# How to reference a zod schema within itself?

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

I'm trying to create a schema that has a function that takes an object with the same schema as an argument.

This example would obviously be wrong as I use `UserSchema` before it was defined:

```js
const UserSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  isEqual: z.function().args(UserSchema).returns(z.boolean()),
});
```

I also tried to do the following:

```js
let UserSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
});

UserSchema = UserSchema.extend({
  isEqual: z.function().args(UserSchema).returns(z.boolean()),
});

type UserInference = z.infer<typeof UserSchema>;
```

but in this case `UserInference` doesn't have `isEqual`:

```js
type UserInference = {
    name: string;
}
```

Are there any options to achieve the expected behaviour?

Comment: Use [`z.lazy`](https://zod.dev/?id=recursive-types)

Comment: @Bergi with `z.lazy` I will not be able to get the type from my schema. I will have to create the type by myself.

Comment: Yes, that is so for recursive types.